# live input managment in kivy

Tags: python, input, kivy

In a part of my app I want to show a list of numbers (1 to 100) and when the "filter" button selected list numbers change (1 to 10). I've tried several solutions like this but none of them worked !
what is the problem in your idea?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button 
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout 
from kivy.uix.listview import ListView
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class SingleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        hole = BoxLayout()
        right = BoxLayout(size_hint_x=0.2)
        left = BoxLayout(size_hint_x=0.8, orientation='vertical')
        side_panel = ListView(item_strings=['no %i' %i for i in range(100)])
        right.add_widget(side_panel)
        btn = Button(text='Show 1 to 10 ')
        lbl = Label(text='Show list of numbers (test)')
        btn2 = Button(text='reset')
        left.add_widget(btn)
        left.add_widget(lbl)
        left.add_widget(btn2)
        hole.add_widget(right)
        hole.add_widget(left)
        btn.bind(on_press=self.change(right))
        btn2.bind(on_press=self.reset(right))
        return hole

    def change(self, side):
        side.clear_widgets()
        side_panel = ListView(item_strings=['NUMBER %i' %i for i in range(10)])
        side.add_widget(side_panel)     

    def reset(self, side):
        side.clear_widgets()
        side_panel = ListView(item_strings=['no %i' %i for i in range(100)])
        side.add_widget(side_panel)     

if __name__=='__main__':
    SingleApp().run()
```

Comment: For starters, the binding of the on_press events for `btn` and `btn2` is incorrect. It should be `btn.bind(on_press=lambda x: self.change(right))` (same goes for `btn1`). Asides from this, what is the problem? Running this code shows a list of 100 elements, and when clicking the filter button, it shows 10 elemnts.

Comment: the main problem was this. i tried a incorrent bind. I think that not understand the bind method in right way.